# How to display php results based on different values returned from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have database table with fields **id**, **text** and **type**. And in **type** I can have values **1** and **2**. I want to display one html output if returned type is 1, and other output if type is 2.

table:

```
id  text       type
1   Some text  1
2   Blah Blah  2
```

So my simple query `SELECT * from table` will return array of values. In my HTML I want to output it like this:

```
<?php foreach ($model as $data): ?>

<h4>Text where status is 1:</h4>  

echo $data['text'];

<h4>Text where status is 2:</h4>

echo $data['text'];

<?php endforeach ?>
```

I have tried with using if inside foreach like this:

```
<?php if ($data['type'] == "1"): ?>
    <h4>Text where status is 1:</h4>

    echo $data['text'];
<?php else: ?>
    <h4>Text where status is 2:</h4>

    echo $data['text'];
<?php endif ?>
```

But this doesn't really work. Is my solution for this to have one query that will return text where type is 1, and another where type is 2 ? Or there is some better solution for this ?

I would like output like this:

```
<h4> Text where status is 1 </h4>    


First text.

Second text.

Third text.


<h4> Text where status is 2 </h4>  


Fourth Text.

Fifth Text.
```

Comment: is `$model` the variable containing the SQL query result?

Comment: Yes it contains query result

Comment: And what is $offer? I mean, what is the condition you need? if $offer is "1" then print the text with status 1 AND $data['text']?

Comment: Sorry, $offer is $data, I forgot to replace name when posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a case, I would go in this way, sir:

```
$outputs = array("1" => array(),"2" => array());

foreach ($model as $data) {
   $outputs[$data['type']][] = $data['text'];
}

foreach ($outputs as $type => $values) {
   echo "<h4>Text where status is {$type}: </h4><br />";
   foreach ($values as $text) {
      echo $text . " <br />";
   }
}
```

Explanation:

We can't, in PHP, print everything inline in such a way, that's why we are:

1. Declaring an array with two values, which are they "$data['type']" that needs to be checked. By doing that, we are declaring the types as key and an array corresponding to each key.
2. While we loop through the results, we push the result inside the correct array of the corresponding key above. passing $output[$data['type']] on a result that has 'type' 2 is the exact same as doing: $output['2']. the next [] means "push that element inside that array", therefore we're literally populating the array according to its key.
3. Because of the structure of the array by looping it again, we loop it by getting the TYPE ("key") and it's value, which is $data['text'] and we print first the type (dinamically, so that if tomorrow you want to add a type 3 you can do that without many issues) and then the values corresponding to its type.

The output:

```
<h4>Text where status is 1: </h4><br />hello <br />ohai dude <br /><h4>Text where status is 2: </h4><br />hello dude <br />
```

From an input array like this:

```
$model = array(
0 => array( "id" => "0",
            "type" => "1",
            "text" => "hello"
            ),
1 => array( "id" => "1",
            "type" => "2",
            "text" => "hello dude"
            ),
2 => array( "id" => "2",
            "type" => "1",
            "text" => "ohai dude"
            )
);
```

Comment: This will output "Text where status is 2" with every row returned where status is 2. I need to output it on top, and then all rows with type of 2 under it.

Comment: On top? what do you mean by "on top"?

Comment: Ooooh okay I got it. Man, you could've been way clearer! Stay tuned.

Comment: I have edited my question by providing example of desired output.

Comment: I have edited my question now, it should be more clear.

Comment: @black-room-boy: I've updated my answer giving you a pretty clear example of how you should be doing that. I'll now add a clearer explanation, but the above code should be working now.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but it is a little bit tricky to output nicely with a lot of html. I go do it. You helped me a lot ! Big thanks!

Comment: @black-room-boy: It's just matter of being used to it. By manipulating a very large amount of data you will find out that using Associative arrays like I did here is much more comfortable than many other solutions ;). The good thing is that in this way you can edit every single thing in your output by just switching a little thing in your array printing. If the array is declared and structured well the output is so elastic that you will never think anymore about the hell you would do without using associative arrays!

Comment: If I have to assign several `$outputs[$data['type']][] = $data['title']; $outputs[$data['type']][] = $data['text']; $outputs[$data['type']][] = $data['image_url'];` How would you print out results nicely in divs ?

Comment: I would personally parse inside it another associative array, like this: `$output[$data['type']][] = array("title" => $data['title'], "type" => $data['type'], "image_url" => $data['image_url'], "text" => $data['text']);`. In this way, the association is like: Array => dataType => array(title,type,imageURL,texT). Therefore, what you will do in such case when you print is keeping the current foreach loop but, instead of `echo $text . " <br />";` you will be able to do: `echo Text: {$text['text']}, Img: {$text['image_url']}` and so on ;) (along with HTML code)

Comment: You're welcome! feel free to ask if you still have any doubt about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// connect to db first
$link = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','database');
// get something from db
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY type");

// loop through result and echo
$flag1 = false;
$flag2 = false;
while($data = mysqli_featch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   if($data['type'] == "1") {
      if(!$flag1) {
         echo '<h4>Text where status is 1:</h4>';
         $flag = true;
      }
      echo $data['text'];
   } else {
      if(!$flag2) {
         echo '<h4>Text where status is 2:</h4>';
         $flag = true;
      }
      echo $data['text'];
   }   
}
```

Comment: I need to have these headlines : `<h4>Text where status is 1:</h4>`. This one is for all text where status is 1, and then comes : `<h4>Text where status is 2:</h4>` with text with status of 2

Comment: Edited query so result is ordered by type. Added flag variables to output only one title.

Comment: @black-room-boy then instead of `echo`ing in the loop, save to an array and then print whatever you want.